# Parent (functions.php) executes but actions doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, wordpress, frontend, wordpress-theming, wp-enqueue-scripts

I'm reading this WordPress Theme flow chart.

[image: wordpress theme flow chart]

I've setup a basic parent/child themes in my wordpress.

**Child Theme (functions.php)**

```
<?php 

echo "child theme";
```

**Parent Theme (functions.php)**

```
<?php 

echo "top";

function coffee_enqueue_styles() {
    echo "parent theme";
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'coffee_enqueue_styles');

echo "bottom";
```

So after I activated my child theme and it loads and executes it's *functions.php* file and print `child theme`. Then WordPress checks if this theme has a parent, it executes it's *functions.php* file and in my case it does and prints `top` and `bottom` but for some reason it doesn't executes the `add_action` hook where I'm printing `enqueued from parent`.

This is the output I get.

[image: output of my child-parent theme execution]

Am I missing something? Please guide me. Thanks you.

#### UPDATE

I changed my action to `init` and it prints `parent theme` at the end of `bottom`. So my action hook is working fine.

Please, Can you please tell me why `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook is not executing or there is any order behind it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the core files. I found that in `wp-includes/default-filters.php`. WordPress is binding `wp_enqueue_scripts` with `wp_head`.

[image: wp_enqueue_scripts inside default-filters]

Which means `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook is only going to work when the `wp_head` hook executes.

So, I was missing [wp_head](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/) function from the template.